# Need table o/p with each FROM_IP its related uid

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

```
index=name conn "connection from"  
    [search index=name 
        [| inputlookup UIDlist.csv 
        |rename UID AS uid
        | fields uid ]
    "BIND"  
   | fields conn ]  
| rex field=_raw "connection from (?<FROM_IP>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+):"  
| stats count by FROM_IP
```

`tst.csv` file has list of UID so that it can give o/p for one user then other and so on ...
I want the table FROM_IP with which uid

O/p of two query used above :

> index=name BIND uid | fields conn

[10/Nov/2020:06:38:40 +0000] conn=111111 op=4238 msgId=4239 - BIND dn="uid=uid,ou=xxx,o=xxxx,o=email" method=128 version=3

> index=name  conn "connection from" | rex field=_raw "connection from
> (?<FROM_IP>\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+):"  | stats count by FROM_IP

[09/Nov/2020:22:52:55 -0800] conn=1111111 op=-1 msgId=-1 - fd=115 slot=115 xxxx connection from xx.xx.xx.xx.xx to xx.xx.xx.xx.xx

Comment: What is "o/p"?  Please elaborate on the problem, including the form of the data and the expected results.

Comment: O/p is in table formate : FROM_IP.    and Count  so I need uid for corresponding FROM_IP

Comment: The uid is not available because it was discarded by the `fields conn` command in the subsearch.

Comment: How can we add UID

Comment: Any other way to write query.

Comment: Since I don't understand your data I can't offer a reasonable alternative query.

Comment: I have added o/p of two separate query used ... can some one help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query.  It's not as efficient as your original query since it reads more rows, but sometimes it can't be helped.
We start by reading both connection and BIND events then putting them together using `stats`.  Then we filter out those not in the lookup file.

```
index=name conn ("connection from" OR "BIND")
| stats values(*) as * by conn
| search [| inputlookup UIDlist.csv 
        |rename UID AS uid
        | return $uid ]
| rex field=_raw "connection from (?<FROM_IP>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+):"
| rex field=dn "uid=(?<uid>[^,]+)"
| stats count by FROM_IP, uid
```

Comment: This is giving events but no o/p for statistics

Comment: Also if possible instead of uid if ‘dn’ value is given out that will also be fine.

Comment: To use dn instead of uid, remove the second `rex` command and replace 'uid' with 'dn' in the second `stats` command.

Comment: Problem here is its not throwing results in stats formate --- means ' stats count by FROM_IP, uid’ field is not working